# multivairable newton raphson complexity

Tags: multidimensional-array, complexity-theory, newtons-method

i have been searching for answers regarding the complexity of the newton raphson method for finding the roots of polynomials over n variables.
for the sake of simplicity, no variable appears in the polynom with degree greater than one.
for example: f(x1,x2,x3) = x1x2x3 - 3*x1x2 + 2*x1x3 + 4*x2x3 -x1 + 2*x2 +x3 + 2

so far i have not found any sufficient reference.
can someone share the complexity of the method, and maybe give a formal reference explaining the complexity analysis ?

thanks :)

Comment: Within the family of [stackexchange](https://stackexchange.com/) sites there are several that are dedicated to various aspects of mathematics. Perhaps this question would be better suited to one of those sites?

Comment: The complexity depends on the expected end precision (assuming that it converges at all)

Comment: can you please elaborate on that ?